# How to disable Wi-Fi, Bluetooth and Camera permanently?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, camera

Need to permanently disable Wi-Fi, bluetooth and camera for work on a few work only devices.
Can this be done through Terminal?
I've tried ifconfig to disable Wi-Fi but it just enables automatically after a few seconds.

I don't need something that literally "permanently" disables Wi-Fi, bluetooth and the camera, just something that isn't very simple for an average user to enable. For instance, I deleted the Camera.apk. I know a user could technically add it back to `/system` but in order to do so they would need root access as well as know to mount `/system` as `rw` instead of `ro`.

Comment: If the devices are rooted, then you can use Link2SD to "freeze" the apps, then you can unroot it afterwards so the apps are locked out. I haven't tried this yet for myself though. Just throwing out suggestions.

Comment: 2021+ if a LineageOS supported device [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/238666/70926) might be possible although some work needed to research board details of your device.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be using a "profile switcher". As your demand is time-based, a good and easy choice would be [Timeriffic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic) (available for free and high rated). Here you could simply say: 24h/day disable these things.

An alternative would be [ProfileScheduler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wetpalm.ProfileScheduler), which also allows switching profiles by click (so you don't need to setup a schedule, just the profile).

Ah, btw: Needless to say that this does not require a rooted device ;)

**Edit:**

If your intention is to keep other people from tempering with certain apps, you might want to take a look at so-called "App Lockers" -- with which you can password-protect some/all your apps (including e.g. the play store app to keep them from installing something else). Here possible candidates include:

- [App Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) (free, high rated)
- [App Protector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobiucare.privacy) (free, good rating)
- [Ultimate App Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anttek.appguard) (free, high rated)

and many more.

And btw2: using an app locker, you can also protect the settings menu (to avoid easy changes to e.g. bluetooth status).

**Edit2:**

If the devices are rooted, you could even bring a "local firewall" into play: Use [Droidwall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) to define which apps may access the internet (via mobile and/or WLAN separately), plus an App Locker to password-protect Droidwall. This way the apps themselves would be accessible (unless you lock them completely as well), but their access to the net would be handled separately (by Droidwall).

Comment: The only problem with those apps is the user can just manually toggle the things we need to disable. I don't need something that literally "permanently" disables wifi, bt and the camera, just something that isn't very simple for an average user to enable.

Comment: Oh -- I missed that part. In this case, try an app locker... Will edit that into my answer.

Comment: I'll see if that route is sufficient.

Comment: OK. I just added a 3rd variant (available in case the devices are rooted) for even more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread to disable WiFi on xdadevelopers: [Permanently Disable WiFi](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/root-permanently-disable-wifi-t3057599).
Author: shmshd12

> First of all I recommend you to make a system backup with TWRP
>
> here we go :
>
> 1. Open ES File Explorer and get Root access
> 2. Go to system folder and open Build.prop using RB Text Editor (i recommend you to backup original file)
> 3. Remove the below mentioned lines in Build.prop Code:

```
     wifi.interface=  
     wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=
```

> 4. save it and reboot