# Salvage Android Phone as Linux-Server (radio/wifi hardware broken)

Tags: wi-fi, custom-roms, reboot, kernel, cellular-radio

My device has hardware problems with radio/wifi. Hence it's not possible to use sim-card or wifi. That also makes it restart frequently. Now it's useless as a phone. So I am trying to turn it in a desk computer (mini-server [linuxdeploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en&gl=US)). Simple air-plane mode isn't enough to solve these reboots.

#### How I figure out its wifi/radio components were broken (tentative)

I have an OnePlus 6 enchilada.

- It fails to detect sim-card and at the same time can't turn on wifi.
- If I try to turn on wifi. In the second I click to turn it on it freezes and reboots.
- I read multiple `logcat` logs to my best efforts. Also system crash dumps. All seams related to radio/wifi or tentatives to turn modem on.
- One think that make its work again (sometimes): is by pressing exactly on the [Qualcomm SDR845 RF transceiver (and also Qualcomm QDM3620, QDM3670, QDM3671 Diversity Receiver Modules)](https://pt.ifixit.com/Teardown/OnePlus+6+Teardown/109826) on the back.
- Other people also faced [similar issues](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/no-sim-card-detected-no-wi-fi-no-imei-random-auto-restart.1132296/page-3) and [same temporary workarounds](https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/hlzhj9/help_oneplus_6_wont_connect_to_sim_or_wifi_and/). They found it to be related with those components. [Repairing the motherboard seams impossible.](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/is-motherboard-repair-possible.320131/) And support want a full motherboard replace which is impractical ($$$).

#### Deeper disable wifi/radio than simple air-plane mode

Is it possible to somehow to disable the WIFI/radio somehow **deeper than simple air-plane mode**? So I can use it as a desk mini-server. Installing [linuxdeploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en&gl=US) or any other software like that and use reverse tethering.

I tried many solutions around internet (including *android.stackexchange*) but none really works.

If someone could give me any tip or advice I would greatly appreciate!!

Comment: Your device has active [LineageOS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/enchilada) support. Therefore you could try to build a custom version of LineageOS and modify the device tree or other parts of the source code to disable the broken components before building the ROM.

Comment: @Robert Hilariously the solution I found is exactly what you commented. Unfortunately I had to spent almost an year of exploration to find that by myself. Thank you anyway for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by myself so I'm sharing so it might be [useful for others](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.185086753.967659742.1623202115-937245380.1618945028).

#### Deeper disable wifi/radio = recompile android Linux Kernel disabling wifi/radio drivers

First I tested the [Lineage OS custom ROM](https://lineageosroms.com/enchilada/#build) for my device.

From that I got access to fully [rebuild my Custom Lineage ROM](https://lineageosroms.com/enchilada/#build). They have all source code for all supported devices including the source for the linux kernel for my mobile board [(Qualcomm SDM845 Snapdragon 845 SoC)](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_oneplus_sdm845).

When the kernel is built It should be decided if It will load driver modules (all SoC board component needs a driver) or have driver modules statically built in it. In either case the driver must be enabled during the kernel build. For configuring the l[inux kernel build](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/ch11s03.html) a `.config` file is used.

After studying a lot more about [linux kernel building](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/kbuild-linux-kernel-build-system). Found from [here](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/OnePlus_6_(oneplus-enchilada)) that QDSP6V5 from OnePlus 6 SoC SDM845 board was mandatory for mobile-data and WIFI when building the kernel.

Using Lineage OS docs and more research and 250 GB of source code and almost 12 hours of download (`repo sync` + `brunch enchilada`) I managed to build my custom Lineage OS 16.0 ROM after modifying the kernel [`.config` fragment](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/configs/) (`enchilada_defconfig`) from [android\lineage\kernel\oneplus\sdm845\arch\arm64\configs\enchilada_defconfig](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_oneplus_sdm845/blob/lineage-17.1/arch/arm64/configs/enchilada_defconfig).

Setting `CONFIG_MSM_PIL_MSS_QDSP6V5` from `y` to `n`(NO).

*Note:* When building LOS I had to disable `dashd` since I couldn't find this file while extracting proprietary blobs. Comment it out on `~/android/lineage/vendor/oneplus/sdm845-common/Android.mk`

```
#include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_MODULE := dashd
#LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := oneplus
#LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_SBIN)
#LOCAL_UNSTRIPPED_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_SBIN_UNSTRIPPED)
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := proprietary/rootfs/sbin/dashd
#LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
#LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES
#include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

and deleting it from  `PRODUCT_PACKAGES +=` list on `sdm845-common-vendor.mk` on same folder.

#### Eureka!!

Wifi and Mobile not working at all.

No more reboots and internet working flawlessly from usb reverse tethering.

Hilariously solution is exactly like @Robert commented. *I had to spent almost an year of exploration to find that by myself.* `-)